# Cannot await 'int' async/await c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

i am trying my hand at using async & await, so i wrote this simple code to get a feel for things. i am writing a web api  and  Post function calls this wrapped storedprocedure.

```
        public async Task<bool> AddNotificationEntryStoredProcedure(NotificationEntry NewNotification, String ExternalRefID)
    {
        try
        {
            Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            Connection.Open();

            Command = new SqlCommand("InsertNewMessage", Connection);
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExternalReferenceID ", ExternalRefID);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageID", NewNotification.id);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recievers", NewNotification.To);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageBody", NewNotification.MessageBody);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryType", NewNotification.DelieveryType);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Response", NewNotification.Feedback);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedOn", DateTime.Now);

            //String TodoDuedate = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", todo.DueDate); // convert date format
            await Command.ExecuteNonQuery(); /*here is where it complains*/

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            //err.ToString();
           return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Connection.Close();
        }


    }// end add function
```

but i get the error saying "cannot await int". how do i fix this thanks for your help.

Comment: Just what the error message says, you can only await something that returns either `Task` or `Task<T>`. `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` returns neither. What you probably want is [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonqueryasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Bless you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` method which calls the overload method `ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` with a `CancellationToken.None`. These methods returns the `Task<int>` you need.